# How to create IADsUser Object and get the Users details like Email

Tags: c++, ldap, adsi

I'm Using LDAP and ADSI.

```
IADsContainer* padsCont = NULL;

hr = ADsGetObject(CONVERTCSTR(szAdsServer), IID_IADsContainer,(LPVOID*)&padsCont);
CoUninitialize();


IADs* pADs;
hr = padsCont->QueryInterface(IID_IADs, (void**)&pADs);

//IADs Interface does not have email but IADsUser has email method/Property which I required. If I pass IADsUser pointer to QueryInterface like

IADsUser* pADsUser;
hr = padsCont->QueryInterface(IID_IADsUser, (void**)&pADsUser);
```

Getting an error E_Interface not Supported.
Could any one help on this. Please ask if need anything to understand clearly

Thanks in advance. 
umar

Comment: what is `szAdsServer`? I suppose the object received (the container) is not an user.

Comment: Its is server name like "LDAP://fabrikam.com"

Comment: Well, "LDAP://fabrikam.com" doesn't look like an user, does not it? A user could be something like "cn=John Doe,dc=example,dc=com" or, even better, like ["LDAP://CN=Jeff Smith,OU=Sales,DC=Fabrikam,DC=Com"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746340(v=vs.85).aspx). Not an user, therefore is does not support IID_IADsUser, as expected.